# MvvmCross Community SQLite-Net plugin error

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, mvvmcross

Hi I'm working wiht MvvmCross 3.5 and I istalled Community SQLite-net plugin but I have this error: Type or namespace 'Community' does not exist in the namespace 'Cirrious.MvvmCross' missing a reference or assembly.
How I can resolve this problem? If anybody have a example using MvvmCross with Community Sqlite, please could share

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded the 3.1 NuGet of the Community plugin, it is not compatible with MvvmCross 3.5.  You need to download the source from here and build it yourself until the new NuGet arrives.  https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-SQLite